# How to solve the Gamma function problem

Tags: gamma-function

This problem appeared in Smith's prize exam 1875.

Evaluate the modulus of

\begin{equation}
\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{-1}a\right)
\end{equation}

If we use the corollary

\begin{equation} 
\Gamma(x)\Gamma\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right) = \frac{\pi^{1/2}}{2^{2x-1}}\Gamma(2x)
\end{equation}

we obtain

\begin{equation} 
\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{-1}a\right)\Gamma(\sqrt{-1}a) = \frac{\pi^{1/2}}{2^{2\sqrt{-1}a-1}}\Gamma(2\sqrt{-1}a)
\end{equation}

Then
\begin{equation} 
\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{-1}a\right) = \frac{\pi^{1/2}}{2^{2\sqrt{-1}a-1}}\frac{(2\sqrt{-1}a-1)!}{(\sqrt{-1}a-1)!}
\end{equation}

This does not lead anywhere. Can anybody help in solving the problem.

Comment: $$|\Gamma(\frac12+ia)|^2=\Gamma(\frac12+ia)\Gamma(\frac12-ia)=\Gamma(\frac12+ia)\Gamma\big(1-(\frac12+ia)\big)$$
$$=\frac\pi{\sin\pi(\frac12+ia)}
=\frac\pi{\cos(\pi ia)}=\frac\pi{\cosh\pi a}$$